# Timing out on passport.authenticate, no idea why

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

When I `POST` to the endpoint that calls `passport.authenticate`, I get no response, nor does the server proceed to the strategy defined in `passport.use`. On Heroku, I get error H12 (timeout), and locally my browser responds with "No data received."

I made [a checkin to GitHub](https://github.com/thure/baxter-app/tree/12d623f08b6659406c632c4821b1aed582dfe50b) with the code that has this problem.

This isn't a database problem – a `console.log` is called before `.findOne`, but that message is never logged. It just seems to stop at `passport.authenticate`. Why?

What's going on here? Is there something else I can do to diagnose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out `passport.authenticate(…)` returns a middleware-style function.

I broke the response chain by calling it the wrong way. In my site.js module, `exports.login` should be set to the result of `passport.authenticate(…)`, it should not call it, i.e.:

```
exports.login = passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/result',
  failureRedirect: '/login'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing [line 38](https://github.com/thure/baxter-app/blob/12d623f08b6659406c632c4821b1aed582dfe50b/app.js#L38) of app.js to either:

```
User.findOne({ id: id }, ...)
```

or

```
User.findById(id, ...)
```

Comment: Hm… that doesn't have an effect. This could have something to do with the session strategy, though – I've started logging messages in relevant parts of passport, and it appears to choke on `strategy.authenticate(req, options)` with the session strategy – it doesn't even get to the local strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your passport config

```js
  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
  });
  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id).then(user => done(null, user));
  });
```